# applying call on java Function<? extends UpboundType, Integer> object and cannot pass object of exact UpboundType to apply( )

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, wildcard

i'm trying to make a exception handler that takes different types of exception argugment, i declared a function type that takes any types that extends Throwable. It can compile when it's declared:

```
Function<? extends Throwable, Integer> handler = (IllegalStateException e) -> {
    return 0;
};
```

but i could't pass throwable or any exception object to it
and i don't understand why...

```
// cannot pass exception object
int result = handler.apply(new IllegalStateException("test"));
```

Anyone knows how to pass the argument correctly?

**[jdk version]:** 1.8

**[error message]:** i got 2 messages:

1. The method apply(capture#6-of ? extends Throwable) in the type Function<capture#6-of ? extends Throwable,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (IllegalStateException)
2. Type mismatch: cannot convert from Function<capture#5-of ? extends Throwable,R> to Function<Throwable,R>

Comment: In the lambda, why did you assume that the exception is `IllegalStateException`? Didn't you say that the handler can handle any type of exception?

Comment: i'm just testing passing one particular exception obj and see if it works.
(it' just an example, the exception argument can be of more possible types)

Answer (score 1):

> i'm trying to make a exception handler that takes different types of exception argugment, i declared a function type that takes any types that extends Throwable

No, you haven't.

The function type you've declared:

```
Function<? extends Throwable, Integer> handler
```

says "this is a Function which accepts *a specific* subclass of `Throwable` - but I don't know which".

You can't pass anything to `handler.accept`, aside from literal `null`, because the compiler doesn't know if the subclass of `Throwable` you're passing is the *right* subclass of `Throwable`.

For example, these are legal assignments:

```
Function<? extends Throwable, Integer> handler1 = (NullPointerException e) -> 0;
Function<? extends Throwable, Integer> handler2 = (IllegalStateException e) -> 0;
```

But those functions can only work correctly if they are passed a `NullPointerException` and `IllegalStateException` respectively. Given just `handler1` and `handler2`, the compiler has no information about which types are expected.

A generic function which accepts any kind of `Throwable` would be:

```
Function<Throwable, Integer> handler
```

No need for bounds.

Don't forget that instances of all subtypes of `Throwable` are also instances of `Throwable`.

Answer (score 0):

Afterwards, 
i found a way that can pass argument without compilation error 
and it can work.

```
// the original one
Function<? extends Throwable, Integer> handler = (IllegalStateException e) -> {
    System.out.println("handle IllegalStateException, msg: " + e.getMessage());
    return 0;
};

// cast it to one that accept specific type
// (instead of just a generic type upbound)
Function<Throwable, Integer> handler_ = (Function<Throwable, Integer>) handler;

// perform call on it
handler_.apply(new IllegalStateException("test"));
```

**output:**
handle IllegalStateException, msg: test

maybe it's solved now 
while i'm not sure if there's other better solution...